# Acer Aspire E1-570 Black Screen, Faulty Bios?

Tags: boot, bios, acer-aspire, black-screen-of-death

Good morning everyone. I am having a bad time trying to fix my laptop Acer Aspire E1-570. I have a black screen of death, when I press the power button the fans start spinning for a second and then stop. The HDD LED start to blink (when the pc worked this LED didn't blink, it was always steady).

[image: Image of the led that is blinking]

As a note: I removed the HDD to avoid any possible data loss, since I think that the problem is related to the BIOS ( I checked before that a laptop can start even without the hard disk, obviously it won't go beyond the BIOS screen).

What I have done so far:

- Removed battery pack, unplugged AC. Make the capacitors discharge by pressing the power button for 20 seconds. Reconnected everything. **Still dead**.
- Read the manual of the PC, too trivial and target to beginner user. Under the section " BIOS " it provides only little or useless informations, like " be sure thata the laptop is connected to AC " or " connect to an external monitor". Done but **still dead**.
- Read on a guide that sometimes these problems are related to an error in the BIOS, in particular is needed a procedure called " clear CMOS" which discharge and reset the BIOS memory. From what I have understood this can be achieved removing the little battery from the mother board or doing a so called " jumper clear" using a wire to connect two particular pins. I didn't find the pins but it must be said that *I'd better leave the disassemble of the laptop as my last chance*, so even here **still dead**.
- I understood, mostly from this [guide](https://www.bios-mods.com/bios-recovery/insyde-bios-recovery/) (but I read thousands), that I could have performed a reset of the BIOS from a USB stick. I searched the web and I found the bios files from the acer site. With further readings I understood that for a boot from USB I would have needed some sort of file with the extension '.bin', '.rom' and the most *talked about in the forums* '.fd' . **With a great disappointment** I found that Acer only releases executable BIOSes from his site, so no rom, fd or bin files. The BIOS was (and actually is) shipped with an embarassing readme.txt saying "run in windows". =/ If I run it displays an error message saying that the architecture is wrong (that's obvious since I was running it on my other HP laptop), and it closes itself. **still dead!**.

  - I finally figured out that it was a fake executable, indeed I was able to extract it as an archive. While unzipping, crossed my fingers, looked at the generated files and found **sadly** only some .sys and .dll files along with another executable called InsyderFlash.exe which opened the same program when run. Tryed to unzip even that executable, found a bunch of files called .text, .srsc and .data. I was unable to find anything useful to do with them. Don't remember where, I found a user **facing the same problem I have** that solved putting the exctracted files on the USB and booting from it pressing, as always Fn+Esc at startup. No need to say it didn't work for me. **3:00 in the morning and still dead**.
  - Finally an idea: before exiting (due to wrong architecture error) the program was doing something, like detecting my current BIOS and other stuff. It was a sort of intuition. I went into my C:\User*name*.AppData\Local\Temp*folder with the name of the downloaded BIOS* and **magically found a new temporary file named** *isflash.bin*. Like a Holy Grail I copied it into the USB stick and tried to boot from it. Well something strange happened. Starting with Fn+Esc the screen lighted up! Then a string message appeared " no bootable device. Need restart" but it was ok since I hadn't connected my hard disk. I then connected my bootable USB with linux Mint, restarted the computer and....... Nothing. Tried to re-do the procedure with the USB stick but no message, no ACER logo, nothing.... **still dead**
  - As my last idea I found (don't remember where, it was 4 a.m. and I browsed thousands of web pages) a strange mystical converter called extractor (v_0.2) from .bin to .fd files. The fact is that I am not able to find the download source because I download it as a 8KB file, which runs only from the command line and has no readme or description. Fact is that I ran the command: *> extractor.exe isflash.bin* and it worked! It created a file .fd, which I renamed with the name of the BIOS. Now I put the file on the USB (formatted as FAT32 as always), plugged into the laptop, started with Fn+Esc held down and.... The computer emitted three long and loud *beeep*, then it shut down. And every time I try the same happens. **still dead??*

Now I ran out of any idea. I could send it to the costumer assistance, but I would like to know if something else still can be done. I am very curious. I know that here on Stack Exchange you are professionists, so, even if I am a noob, I tried to be the more accurate as possible and I tried to do everything before posting here the question.

Feel free to ask any detail. Bye and thank you very much for the help.

---

Comment: How many times does the light flash? Its a code.. There should be a series of flashes then a pause, or just a constant steady flash. What color is the light? How much of a pause between flashes? Also, there is no CPU LED. You'll have a power LED and possibly a hard drive activity LED.

Comment: he is likely referring to the HDD light as people often mistake it for cpu as it indicates activity

Comment: I'm thinking not as the HDD activity light flashes. It may seem solid during high periods of usage but the fact that he unplugged the HDD it shouldn't blink at all. Maybe if the port is being probed but that is all.

Comment: Yes you are right. It is the HDD led (edited the question with the image of the blinking led). Actually is strange because I unplugged it. Do you think that I should add that the light on the USB is stady on as soon as I start the pc and then starts to blink before and during the emission of the three beeps? seems that it is reading something.

Comment: Kisk the I didn't pay attention to how many times the led blinks and if there is a pattern. I left the laptop at home, I will give it a look and edit the question with this detail. The LED is blue as always.

Comment: 3 Beeps? This is important information and the first you've mentioned beeps. Try to hook up the laptop to an external display as well and see if you get anything.

Comment: Actually it is "emphasized" in the last point :) and I think I should focus on it but I didn't find anything on google. Connected to an external monitor with HDMI and nothing appears

Answer (score 0):

Very likely you are experiencing Black Screen of Death common on Acer Aspire E1 series laptops. This is a partial or complete failure of the WinBond W25Qxxxxx or other BIOS Chip. Acer Aspire E1 series provides a method of recovering BIOS from FD or BIN file via External USB Flash Drive, which you have described.

- CMOS Reset: Your laptop probably contains a soldered/spot-welded Lithim Ion 3.3V coin cell, which is not easily removed without cutting/de-soldering, to clear the CMOS use a paper clip/copper wire/alligator clip to temporarily jumper between the wires leading directly out of the CMOS battery, while Laptop battery is removed, and AC power removed, and momentarily depressing the power button to discharge.
- USB Flash Recovery BIN: As you have eluded to, to attempt Acer Aspire recovery you need to copy isflash.bin to external USB Flash drive, this file may need to be renamed. Using **PheonixTool** or similar "https://forums.mydigitallife.net/threads/tool-to-insert-replace-slic-in-phoenix-insyde-dell-efi-bioses.13194/" you may be able to gleam the filename required. For best results a maximum 2GB USB Flash drive USB2.0/1.1 compatible formatted as FAT32/FAT16. You can do this in Windows using DISKPART "https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/windows/it-pro/windows-server-essentials-sbs/jj200124(v=ws.11)?redirectedfrom=MSDN", isflash.bin is obtained using the method you described, running the *.exe extracted from the BIOS *.zip and acquiring *isflash.bin* from *"C:\Users$USERNAME\AppData\Local\Temp"*
- USB Flash Recovery FD: If you were unsuccessful with the previous attempt, you may need to extract the *.FD file from with within *isflash.BIN*. To do this you you can use **InsydeImageExtractor** "https://github.com/LongSoft/InsydeImageExtractor", *ex.* `extractor.exe isflash.bin BIOS.FD`, renamed the *.FD file the name you discovered in the previous step. Copy *.FD file to external USB Flash 2GB formatted as FAT16, attempt **FN+ESC** recovery.
- SOIC8 BIOS Flash ISP: Last Resort you can use flashrom/frser-duino/Bus Pirate and attempt to Read/Erase/Flash the BIOS using SOIC8/Pomona Clip. "https://www.flashrom.org", "https://github.com/urjaman/frser-duino", "http://dangerousprototypes.com/docs/Bus_Pirate"

Notes:

- The USB slot on the laptop used for recovery may be specific, if unsure try them all.
- A Flash Stick with LED helps during this process alot, it will tell you when the drive is being read by the BIOS

Answer (score -1):

If the LED light you speak of is the power indicator LED that is flashing then it is most likely saying you don't have enough power to start the laptop. Typically this light will stay solid (usually amber color) if the laptop is plugged up with the AC adapter but the battery is not fully charged. When the battery is fully charged this light may change (usually blue).

If you hit the power button and the laptop powers on, then off, followed by the power LED flashing then I would first suspect the power supply. Have you tried another power brick? Anything within 0.5v will work as long as the plug matches. Don't worry about (A)mps.

Even if you've tested your power supply with a multimeter and it shows the correct voltage this does not mean your PSU is good. Correct readings need to be taken when the PSU is *under load*, ie actively having power drawn from it. This is difficult to do while it is plugged in as you won't have access to the lead contact in the middle of the plug.

Try a new adapter and post back.

Comment: I disagree with most of this answer. If the laptop didn't have enough power, it would not work the one time it did, and likely would not turn on at all. Additionally, amperage is as big a problem as voltage. Some laptops will auto shut-down if the amprage is too low.

Comment: I disagree with you. If the PSU is faulty, it may still put off a low amount of power.. enough to turn on the power LED and any addition will *slowly* trickle to the battery. I run a computer repair shop btw and see this all the time. As far as amperage, this model will work fine off anything > 3amp @ 19v. In fact, he's very unlikely to find a charger with less than this with the same connector.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. I don't have another adapter to try in this moment. I'll find one asap and post back if something has changed. Oh, I figured out that the LED that is blinking is the HDD led (updated the question)

Comment: @kisk Lol, I work with repairing computers too, but oddly, I've never seen that exact issue being caused by a power supply. I will admit that they do cause odd issues though. Seems unlikely it's a psu issue if it's the hdd light blinking now. Sounds more like a firmware corrupted issue to me. Bios flash might help. One way to check if the power supply is dead would be to plug it in for a long time while it's off, charging the battery, and then try to turn it on without the ac power plugged in. If it works, the problem is then the power cord. If it doesnt, the problem still may or may not be it